# Remove element from a list with a specific id lisp

Tags: list, lisp

I'm trying to do a function in lisp that removes an element from a board given a specific id. My board is a two-dimension array, and in each position I have something like this: `(value (id x y)(id x y)...(id x y))`. I have to delete every `(id x y)` triplet in which the id equals the int given in the function call.
I've come up with a probably very bad solution which copies the content of the board into a new one, except the elements that have the specified id. I've tried running a few examples on the console and it returns the correct result but it doesn't change the contents of the array. Isn't the set at the end of the function supposed to do exactly that? Also, I was expecting that the console result would be `T`or `NIL`and not the modified board...

```
(defun remove-id (board int)
  (let ((lin (board-lines board))
        (col (board-columns board)))
    (let ((new-board (new-board lin col)))
      (dotimes (i lin)
        (dotimes (j col)
          (when (not (null (aref board i j)))
            (dolist (el (rest (aref board i j))
              (if (not (= (el-id el) int))
                (copy-content new-board (el-x el)(el-y el)))))))
      (setf board (copy-board new-board)))))
```

All of the functions that I'm using work correctly, I hope the names are self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [`remove`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) *nondestructive* family of functions or the `delete` *destructive* family.
One of them can replace your `dolist` loop.

More specifically, you need to do something like

```
(setf (board-content new-board x y) 
      (remove int (board-content old-board x y) :key #'car))
```

The important parts are

1. the `:key` argument (otherwise you are comparing `int` with `(id ...)`, not with `id`)
2. the `setf` call (since `remove` does not modify its sequence argument)

(note also that you can replace your two `let`s with a single `let*`).

Comment: I've changed the lines below the second dotimes to this: `(remove obj (rest (aref board i j)))` but this doesn't do anything. I've tried a simple example on the console where obj would be something like `(1 (1 (0 . 0)(1 . 1)))` and I tried removing the object with the id=1. The result was NIL...